# rails model validattion ( not containing a substring)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

Is there a simple way to validate that a fields not containing a sub string. I would like a email field not containing 'yahoo.com'. If it contains 'yahoo.com' I would lile to return an error messaage.

Comment: Writing your own custom validator seems to be the simplest way of achieving this
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need to add a custom validator just use Rails validates_format_for

```
validates_format_of :email, without: /yahoo\.com/i, message: "your custom message"
```

see documentation
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of

Comment: Thanks, how about not containing both yahoo.com and hotmail.com ?

Comment: if you're going to add complexity, and add multiple texts you don't want to have in there you should build a custom matcher as i demonstrate below - you really should isolate that in one place so you isolate changes to that one place

Comment: you just need to adjust the regular expression for without: validates_format_of :email, without: /(yahoo|hotmail)\.com/i, message: "your custom message"

Answer (score 2):

As the comment suggests - build a custom validator

```
require 'active_model'

class NotYahooEmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if value.include? "yahoo.com"
      object.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is a yahoo.com email address")
    end
  end

end
```

You would use this as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :not_yahoo_email => true
end
```

Comment: Did you mean `NotYahooEmailValidator`? :)

Comment: funny i was JUST adding that correction as you typed the comment :-) ...great minds think alike